# Custom input to force Pattern.compile throw PatternSyntaxException

Tags: java, regex

I have one line of java code below, input can be any string

My question is, is it even possible to make this line throw PatternSyntaxException?

tried several inputs, but none of these can fail this line.

```java
Pattern.compile("[" + Pattern.quote(input) + "]+")
```

Comment: Your title seems to suggest that question is about *existing* exception, not about *possibility* of exception. Please [edit] it and make it more obvious for people who would want to find this topic.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you expecting an exception? Why?

Comment: I am trying to see if any inputs can break this line of code. Try to have a better understanding of regex.

Comment: Usually `Pattern.quote` will quote regex metachars. Some languages do it with `\W` which will cause a problem. But if just the 12 metachars, which inside of classes, most of the escapes are ignored. Some aren't. Is `-` a metacharacter ? Dunno, but if you put in an invalid range, that _will_ throw an exception.

Comment: @sln "but if you put in an invalid range, that will throw an exception" not really, since Pattern.quote uses `\Q..\E` to create quotation section which is also respected by character classes. So even if input will be like `a-` then it will generate `[\Qa-\E]` which will be same as `a|-`.

Comment: @StephenChen Purpose of `Pattern.compile` is to escape sequence of characters. It is done by surrounding it with `\Q...\E` which creates quotation section also respected by `[..]`. Inside that section only `\E` sequence is special because it represents end od that section, so it will be escaped additionally. If your input will be `a\Eb` it will be escaped like `[\Qa\E\\E\Qb\E]` which means it will match either `a` or ``\`` or `E` or `b` (each character from `a\Eb`).

Comment: Honestly I doubt you can get `PatternSyntaxException` here, if you would it would most likely be a bug in language (which is possible but unlikely). I was thinking about surrogate-pair support for character class, but it also seems to be supported in character class (tested with `input` containing ).

Comment: @Pshemo - Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Pshemo, thanks, yeah, I don't think I can get PatternSyntaxException here either.